# What does the command DIAG 3411 do?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

Im trying to understand a few lauterbach commands, may i know what does the DIAG 3411 do? Should the system be in any specific state for it to be executed? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands starting with DIAG are unofficial and undocumented diagnostic commands. You should contact the Lauterbach hotline to get details about that command if you really need to.

Anyhow, when looking at the AREA window when executing `DIAG 0x3411` it looks pretty much like a command to scan the Arm CoreSight DAP. I recommend to use the official command `SYStem.DETECT.DAP` instead to scan your CoreSight DAP.